# How to include a WebAssembly module in a Flutter Web application?

Tags: flutter, rust, webassembly, flutter-web

I'm trying to extend my Flutter Web application with some Rust code via WebAssembly. My project structure looks like this:

```
lib/
- main.dart
web/
  - wasm_demo/
     - src/
       - lib.rs
     - pkg/
       - wasm_demo.js
       - wasm_demo_bg.wasm
     - bootstrap.js
     - Cargo.toml
  - index.html
```

The Rust code just creates a `String` and returns it:

```rust
// web/wasm_demo/src/lib.rs

use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get_string() -> String {
    String::from("This is a Rust String!")
}
```

When compiled with `wasm-pack build` the bytecode ends up in `web/wasm_demo/pkg/wasm_demo_bg.wasm`. `wasm_demo.js` is just a JavaScript module exporting the `get_string` function from `wasm_demo_bg.wasm`:

```js
import * as wasm from './wasm_demo_bg.wasm';

...

/**
* @returns {string}
*/
export function get_string() {
    ...
}
```

`bootstrap.js` imports that module and puts it into the `window` object:

```js
// bootstrap.js

import * as wasm_demo from "./pkg/wasm_demo";

window.wasm_demo = wasm_demo;
```

`index.html` loads that bootstrapper prior to launching the actual application:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rust/WASM/Flutter interop demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="wasm_demo/bootstrap.js" type="module"></script>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And finally, Flutter displays the Rust `String`:

```dart
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Rust/WASM/Flutter interop demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext buildContext) {
    var rustString = context["wasm_demo"].callMethod('get_string').toString();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Rust/WASM/Flutter interop demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(rustString),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that `wasm_demo_bg.wasm` is apparently not included in the bundle:

```
:44809/wasm_demo/pkg/wasm_demo:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there any way to tell Flutter that the WebAssembly module is needed in the bundle? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using Emscripten, you can generate two files, a `.js` and a `.wasm` via

```
emcc -o build/wasm_demo.js web/wasm_demo/src/lib.rs
```

When invoking, specify the `.js` file you just built, and it should automatically fetch its complimenting `.wasm` file:

```
import wasmDemo from './build/wasm_demo.js'
new wasmDemo({
  onRuntimeInitialized() {
    console.log('wasm ready', this._get_string());
  }
});
```